# How to query Netflix using YQL?

Tags: yql, netflix

What is a query to select data from NetFlix API using YQL?

I tried to run select* from netflix.catalog where key = "xxxxx";

but got an error Cannot find required keys in where clause; got 'key', expecting required keys: (cks, term, ck)

update: I checked it asks for SELECT * FROM netflix.catalog WHERE term="" and ck="" and cks=""

What are these parameters and how to query a movie from that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very detailed example of an netflix app using YQL [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-tutorials.html). The netflix specific stuff begins under the header ***Setting Up This Example***

Here's their first query that clearly shows the values of cks,term, and ck.

```
USE "http://your_domain/netflix.xml" AS netflix_table; SELECT * FROM netflix_table WHERE term="rocky" AND ck="your_consumer_key" AND cks="your_consumer_secret__key"
```

**ck:** consumer_key
**cks:** consumer_secret
**term:** search term